# What do I do when I can't find archived emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I cannot find my archived emails. I cannot get it to pull up ALL mail or Archived or More with the arrow. I have tried over and over. What do I do?

Comment: I think we need a little more information. What's your browser? Do you have JavaScript enabled? Any script blockers?

Answer (score 2):

1. Log out. Clear your cache and cookies. Restart your browser. Log in
   again and try again by clicking on `All Mail`.
2. Use another browser and see if it works there.